# Regex Negative Lookbehind Variable Distance

Tags: .net, regex, lookbehind

I'm trying to use a regex to find something in a later-occurring groupB that does not exist in the earlier groupA.  It's fine if it exists in A, but not B.  This seems to imply the necessity of a negative lookbehind if I must use a regex.

Massively simplified example:

Text:

```
groupA:
tag 789
tag 123

groupB:
Item 1:
... 123
... 456
```

I'm rather new to lookarounds.  This is what immediately came to mind (or one of a dozen variations) but the informed among you will see that it does not work as intended.

```
regex:(\.\.\. (?<ID>(\d+)))(?<=(?s).*?tag (\k<ID>))
```

My ideal goal would be to match items in groupB that do not exist in groupA and I cannot reorder the input.  Correct example output: (not done by the provided regex)

```
... 456
```

.NET supports variable lookback distance, but obviously I'm missing something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET regex engine parses characters from left to right, so you can't backreference from right to left. By the time you reach group B, all the characters in group A have already been consumed & can't be matched against. While regex may appear to backtrack, it's actually [prematching or branching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4.aspx) - the parser never runs backwards.

With a forward-running parser, you'd need to match (and retain) items in group A first, then only return items from group B if they weren't present in group A. This is too complex for a [deterministic finite automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automata) to calculate, as it can't be done in constant space.

You *could* solve your problem using regular expressions by reversing your string and running your matches backwards, but the code could get pretty incomprehensible:

```
321 ...
:1 metI
:Bpuorg

321 gat
987 gat
:Apuorg

"((?<id>\d+)(?=\s\.\.\.))(?!.*\k<id>\sgat)"
```

Result:

```
"654"
```

Instead, I'd suggest keeping it simple with something like this:

```
var groupA = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=tag\s)\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
var groupB = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\.\.\.\s)\d+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);

var bNotA = groupB.Except(groupA);
```

Comment: This is basically exactly what I suspected earlier, but could find nothing to support my supposition.  I had considered turning the string around, but it's just not quite "right."  The operation I ask for with the requirement of a single forward pass would necessarily remove a regular expression from consideration in favor of a structure capable of supporting bulk storage.  I'll have a chat with my coworker and see if we can attack this from a different angle altogether.  Thank you very much for your time, sir.

Comment: Regular expressions, as implemented in most common flavours, are way more powerful than DFAs. Even when you add plain backreferences you're already matching more than regular languages. Furthermore, the optimisations that avoid backtracking you mentioned are only applied when the pattern doesn't use any backreferences. As soon as there are backreferences even .NET's regex flavour will revert to backtracking. And lastly lookbehinds *are* matched from right to left. All of that aside, I do prefer your solution (not doing everything with a  single regex) for production code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, and you're probably no longer interested in a solution yourself, but I find the existing answer misleading, and wanted to provide another one. (The final solution in the other answer is great for the given problem - you don't need to solve everything with a single regex. But the problem pointed out in your answer was not actually the problem.)

Your idea was actually correct, but the implementation not. The first problem is that you're using a positive lookbehind which would ensure that the same value *has* appeared before. What you want is negative lookbehind, `(?<!...)` to ensure that the value *hasn't* appeared.

The main problem however is that the order of the content of your lookbehind is wrong. In your code you *first* have the wildcard `.*?` and *then* the thing you want to match `tag (\k<ID>)`. But you are looking for `tag X` somewhere to the *left* of your current position, which means that the wildcard actually needs to go second. In a look*behind* the current position of the regex engine (outside of the lookbehind) is at the *end* of the pattern inside. Imagine doing `(?<=abc)def`. This matches `def` in `abcdef` but not in `cbadef`. (More to the point, if `.*?` had to go in front, why would `tag (\k<ID>)` itself not be reversed like `(\k<ID> gat)`?

So this works perfectly fine:

```
(\.\.\. (?<ID>(\d+)))(?<!(?s)tag (\k<ID>).*?)
```

Although it has a lot more groups than you actually need. This is sufficient:

```
\.\.\. (?<ID>\d+)(?<!(?s)tag \k<ID>.*?)
```

[Test it here.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%5c.%5c.+(%3f%3cID%3e%5cd%2b)(%3f%3c!(%3fs)tag+%5ck%3cID%3e.*%3f)&i=groupA%3a%0d%0atag+789%0d%0atag+123%0d%0a%0d%0agroupB%3a%0d%0aItem+1%3a%0d%0a...+123%0d%0a...+456)

As for Simon's comment "The .NET regex engine parses characters from left to right, so you can't backreference from right to left." I don't know about that. I haven't seen the regex engine's code but from years of experimenting with .NET's regex flavour and abusing it for all sorts of shenanigans, I can say that it certainly *appears* to backtrack as you'd expect for all practical purposes. (The faster algorithms he linked to are only applied to patterns that don't use backreferences, where the results are completely indistinguishable.) Patterns are matched from left to right, yes. But a lookbehind isn't processed until you actually reach the lookbehind in the pattern, and it can backreference earlier captures, even if those end up *later* in the match.

The two caveats to this are that a) .NET has a right-to-left matching mode which actually processes the pattern from right to left, so captures have to appear *after* their backreferences in the code and b) lookbehinds use said right-to-left mode (this is unfortunately undocumented), so that the engine can actually weave back and forth through the input string by using lookbehinds in normal left-to-right patterns (or lookaheads in side right-to-left patterns, or lookaheads inside lookbehinds and what not, but that's probably not something you want to use in production code).

This direction of processing the input is *always* important when considering when backreferences are valid and when not.